# Is there a backend method for converting WordPress classic WYSIWYG content to the HTML-based classic block content React generates in Gutenberg?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In WordPress, classic WYSIWYG editor content is formatted with newlines and returns, like in a text editor. If you switch over to the block editor, that content remains formatted that way - until you add any other block. Once you add another block, React reformats the content to HTML - for instance, wrapping content in paragraph tags.

We are migrating 25,000+ pages, so a backend solution is ideal. Does anyone know if a backend method for this has been written? I'm wondering if I'm missing a solution that already exists since surely others have had this same need. TIA for any leads.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar situation with migrating to blocks from legacy content. The issue as you noted is the frontend triggers the "Convert to Blocks" for existing content. There is a plugin, "[Convert to Blocks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-to-blocks/)" which depending on your content, may/may not work for your content. Given how many pages you have, I would test it out on a sample of various pages to gauge its effectiveness first before running it on Production.